# Branding for SharePoint on Mobile

Tags: branding, image-display, mobile

I've managed to create a very basic CSS for my SharePoint site and added some CSS queries to manage the CSS being loaded when on a mobile device.

My issue is that thought it renders the HTML setup properly, it doesn't render my background images nor borders on some occations.

I've used [this site](http://www.quirksmode.org/m/css.html) to check which CSS selectors and attributes works on specific phones (I'm aiming for iPhone only at the moment since that's the only phone I'm able to check my site on for now).

The image files are .PNG and doesn't render at all. Neither does the basic CSS attribute `Border`. All other core.css styles gets rendered as they should.

Clip out of my CSS. (This is my navigation)

```
/*  TOP NAVIGATION  */

.menu-horizontal A.static{
    float: none;
}

.s4-tn UL.root > LI.static > .menu-item:first-child{
    display:none;
}

.menu-horizontal UL.root > LI.static > UL.static > LI.static > .menu-item{
    background-image: url('/Style Library/Images/dummy.png');
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: solid 1px black;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 34px 0px 3px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 95px;
}

.menu .menu-item{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The *dummy.png* doesn't get rendered, but *gosearch15.png* (which is a standard sharepoint search icon) gets rendered normally. How come?

Comment: What if you try /Style%20Library/Images/dummy.png ? Does that url actually point to somwhere?

Comment: @JanisVeinbergs Yes, that points to the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why. It's because of the differences between how browsers render HTML and so it differentiates on mobile devices as well.

So where there might be a `<li>` in IE, there's a `<span>` in Safari etc.

Comment: Cross Browser can get really tricky: I use some of the tools shown here to help: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/tools-browser-compatibility-check/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add !important to the relevant CSS directives like this:

```
background-image: url('/Style Library/Images/dummy.png') !important;
background-position: center top !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
border: solid 1px black !important;
```

Sometimes it works for me